# Is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n) = \mathbb{P}(\cup_n A_n)$?

Tags: probability-theory

On the bottom of page 22 of the [lecture notes](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~rvan/acm217/ACM217.pdf) of R van Handel, part 4 of Lemma 1.2.1 states that, for a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$,
\begin{equation}
A_1 \subset A_2 \cdots \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n) = \mathbb{P}(\cup_n A_n).
\end{equation}

> Does this result require some additional assumptions, say, on the continuity
>   of the probability measure?

For example, consider the following measure:
$$
P = \frac{1}{2}U(0,1) + \frac{1}{2}\delta_{1},
$$
that is $P$ is a scaled uniform measure on $[0,1]$ of total mass $0.5$ and a mass of size $0.5$ at $1$.

Let $A_n = [0,1-1/n]$. Then, $\cup_n A_n = [0,1]$ and $P(\cup_n A_n) = 1$. However, $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n) = 1/2 \neq P(\cup_n A_n)$.

> Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Kenny Lau: could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\cup_n A_n = [0,1)$ not $[0,1]$, so its measure is still $0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

No additional assumptions are required.

Let $B_1=A_1$ and $B_{n+1}=A_{n+1}-(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n)$ for $n=1,2,\dots$

Then $A_n=B_1\cup\cdots\cup B_n$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n$ and the sets $B_i$ are measurable and disjoint.

That leads to: $$P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\right)=P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(B_k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(B_k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)$$